# Cryptography Unit Testing Logic

Tags: c#

I'm relatively new to C# and I've just learnt cryptography (symmetric and one way hash). Now I can surely create two methods that encrypt/decrypt text and they work fine. I encountered my problem when I tried to unit test the two methods. What do I test exactly? If I use for example TDES or AES to encrypt, there's not a single online encrypter that gives the same cipher text ( let alone that no online encrypter gives the same result of another one) for me to use as an expected result to compare with my actual result, so how do I verify that my method actually encrypted my text? Also are there any other logical tests to run on such methods?

Comment: You should get the same results as long as you use the same settings (key, mode, IV, padding, block size, etc.). It looks like most online tools only let you specify a key (and maybe the mode and IV), and they may be using different input/output formats, so you'll have to take that into account if you want to compare your results to theirs.

Comment: For the core cryptographic primitives, there should be published test vectors - but hopefully you're not re-implementing the primitives and they've already been tested and certified. As Pieter says, you need to control all of the inputs so if your current methods include e.g. automatic generation of IV/Nonce or key material, you will need to separate that out.